# symfony2 - doctrine - oneToMany

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I've defined the following relationships in my entities:

Entity Area

```
/**
 * @var areaHasCategory $categories
 * 
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="areaHasCategory", mappedBy="area", cascade={"ALL"})"
 */    
private $categories;
```

Entity areaHasCategory

```
/**
 * @var area $area 
 * 
 * @ORM\Id 
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="area", inversedBy="categories")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="pkfkArea", referencedColumnName="pkId", nullable=false) 
 */
private $area;

/**
* @var category $category
*
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="category", inversedBy="areas")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="pkFkCategory", referencedColumnName="pkId", nullable=false)
*/
private $category;
```

Entity category

```
/**
* @var areaHasCategory $areas
* 
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="areaHaCategory", mappedBy="category", cascade={"ALL"})"
*/
private $areas;
```

When i'm reading a area from the database in my controller, the arrayCollection for categories is empty.
I saved data with a fixture. 
The profiler shows all select statements and when i exceute the query which reads data from the category Table, everything is fine.
But $area->getCategories() is empty.

Has anybody an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: has nobody an idea for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to not use @ORM\Id for relations fields and add a separate field for primary key.

Comment: i posted just example code. The original City Table has two foreign keys and these keys together are unique. do you think this is a problem?